# I have no good idea how to use the terminal and basic commands

Tags: windows, wine

Currently I am trying to install roblox and I have a good guide but there are always error messages regarding something called "trust" and "conflicting values" I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 wine and my brain can't handle all this. I can't afford a windows computer at the moment and I'm trying to use this but it is SO FRUSTRATING!!

TL;DR: where can I learn the basics of the terminal and how can I install wine Ubuntu 20.04????

Comment: `sudo apt install wine` will install `wine`.  The `sudo` elevates privileges so the command can write to system directories; `apt` is the package tool which you give the command `install` to install a package; `wine` being the package you want installed.

Comment: Installing Wine has nothing to do with learning basics of the terminal. Making Windows run on Linux is extremely difficult. Here is a link for Roblox: https://gamertweak.com/how-to-play-roblox-linux/